# What command in Stata 12 do I use to interpret the coefficients of the Limited Dependent Variable model?

Tags: stata, margins

I am running the following code:

```
oprobit var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var2##var3 var4##var5 var6 var7 etc.
```

Without the interaction terms I could have used the following code to interpret the coefficients:

```
mfx compute, predict(outcome(2))
```

[for outcome equaling 2 (in total I have 4 outcomes)]

But since `mfx` does not work with the interaction terms, I get an error.
I tried to use
`margins` command, but it did not work either!!!
`margins var2 var3 var4 var5 var2##var3 var4##var5 var6 var7 etc... , post`

`margins` works ONLY for the interaction terms: `(margins var2 var3 var4 var5, post)`
What command do I use to be able to interpret BOTH interaction and regular variables?

Finally, to use simple language, my question is: given the regression model above, what command can I use to interpret the coefficients?

Comment: The report "`margins` does not work either" is not easy to decode unless you state the exact command you used and the exact response from Stata.

Comment: @Nick Cox I used `margins var2 var3 var4 var5, post`  As you can see I did not include other variables (like var6, var7 etc.) that do not interact with anbody. My point is that `mfx` works ONLY for regular (NON INTERACTION) variables, and `margins` works ONLY for variables that interact with somebody.

Comment: That's half of what I suggested, the exact command you used (although as a side-issue it's much better to use evocative variable names, not names like `var1`). But your summary is wrong. `margins` will produce results for factor variables; they do not have to be involved in interactions.

Comment: @Nick Cox I have evocative name, but if I showed actual name, that would require additional explanations...and would make my question longer. All my variable area categorical. With respect to `margins`, I got my mistake, I should have used: `margins, dydx(*) predict(outcome(2))` as @Dimitriy V. Masterov suggested below.

Comment: I see. If you present code as literal code, that is what people will take it to be. The difference turns out to be irrelevant to your problem here, but that's not true in general. It's dangerous not to cite the exact code you used, as you could remove some small detail that is crucial to understanding a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mfx is an old command that has been replaced with margins. That is why it does not work with factor variable notation that you used to define the interactions. I am not clear what you actually intended to calculate with the margins command.

Here's an example of how you can get the average marginal effects on the probability of outcome 2:

```
. webuse fullauto
(Automobile Models)

. oprobit rep77 i.foreign c.weight c.length##c.mpg

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -89.895098  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -76.800575  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -76.709641  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -76.709553  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -76.709553  

Ordered probit regression                         Number of obs   =         66
                                                  LR chi2(5)      =      26.37
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0001
Log likelihood = -76.709553                       Pseudo R2       =     0.1467

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         rep77 |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     1.foreign |   1.514739   .4497962     3.37   0.001      .633155    2.396324
        weight |  -.0005104   .0005861    -0.87   0.384    -.0016593    .0006384
        length |   .0969601   .0348506     2.78   0.005     .0286542     .165266
           mpg |   .4747249   .2241349     2.12   0.034     .0354286    .9140211
               |
c.length#c.mpg |  -.0020602   .0013145    -1.57   0.117    -.0046366    .0005161
---------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         /cut1 |   17.21885   5.386033                      6.662419    27.77528
         /cut2 |   18.29469   5.416843                      7.677877    28.91151
         /cut3 |   19.66512   5.463523                      8.956814    30.37343
         /cut4 |   21.12134   5.515901                      10.31038    31.93231
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

.  margins, dydx(*) predict(outcome(2))

Average marginal effects                          Number of obs   =         66
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Pr(rep77==2), predict(outcome(2))
dy/dx w.r.t. : 1.foreign weight length mpg

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
   1.foreign |  -.2002434   .0576487    -3.47   0.001    -.3132327    -.087254
      weight |   .0000828   .0000961     0.86   0.389    -.0001055    .0002711
      length |  -.0088956    .003643    -2.44   0.015    -.0160356   -.0017555
         mpg |   -.012849   .0085546    -1.50   0.133    -.0296157    .0039178
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: dy/dx for factor levels is the discrete change from the base level.
```

If you want the prediction, rather than the marginal effect, try

```
margins, predict(outcome(2))
```

The marginal effect of just the interaction term is harder to calculate in a non-linear model. Details [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0063).

Comment: Also, it's Stata, not STATA. This rubs some people the wrong way.

Comment: Thank You for reply. I have voted up. However, I have done `margins, predict(outcome(2))`. My problem is: I cannot directly interpret the estimated coefficient of the regression because this is a limited dependent variable model. That is why I need first to transform those coefficients, so that I would be able to interpret them (say 1 point increase in var2 causes 25% probability of dependent variable to be equal to 2). `mfx` used to do the transformation: `mfx compute, predict(outcome(2))` you can try this. But it does not accept interaction terms.

Comment: In your example  `margins, dydx(*) predict(outcome(2))` does not transform  `c.length#c.mpg` coefficient, which originally equals to -.0020602. How do I explain this -.0020602?

Comment: Let's say you care about length. The AME for length includes the direct effect of length as well as the effect from the interaction with mpg. Why would you ever want to separate the two? If you care what that looks like at different values of mpg, you can add something like `at(mpg =(15 25 35))` option to the margins.

Comment: Here's another loose way to see this. Pr(y=2)=F(a + b x + c z + d x*z). The derivative with respect to x is F'(a + b x + c z + d x*z)(b+d*z) by the chain rule. You evaluate that for everyone and get the average. That's the AME. The at() option evaluates this average with everyone's mpg set at 15, 25, and 35.

Comment: Thank you @Dimitriy V. Masterov

Answer (score 0):

```
The marginal effects for positive outcomes, Pr(depvar1=1, depvar2=1), are
        . mfx compute, predict(p11)
The marginal effects for Pr(depvar1=1, depvar2=0) are
        . mfx compute, predict(p10)
The marginal effects for Pr(depvar1=0, depvar2=1) are
        . mfx compute, predict(p01)
```